# Fazer um count em relacionamento Muitos para Muitos

Tags: python, django

Estou tentando colocar em uma view a quantidade de alunos inscritos em um curso usando os seguintes Models abaixo.

OBS: Não posso alterar as colunas dos Models, visto que o banco de dados já existe e eu estou apenas fazendo um outro sistema a partir dele.

Mas como que funciona? Assim:

> **1** curso (MdlCourse) tem **N** tipos de inscrição (MdlEnrol).
>
> **N** tipos de inscrição tem **N** matrículas. (MdlUserEnrolments)

```
class MdlCourse(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class MdlUserEnrolments(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    status = models.BigIntegerField()
    enrolid = models.ForeignKey(MdlEnrol, on_delete = False, db_column = 'enrolid')

class MdlEnrol(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    enrol = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    status = models.BigIntegerField()
    courseid = models.ForeignKey(MdlCourse, on_delete = False, db_column = 'courseid')
```

O Model MdlUserEnrolments não tem o ID do curso. Ele tem o ID do tipo de inscrição. E a tabela de tipo de inscrição tem o ID do curso.

Ou seja, preciso caminhar duas tabelas para ter a quantidade de alunos inscritos. Isso usando os métodos de relacionamento do Django, pois não queria fazer um `RawSQL`.

O que eu consegui até agora:

```
{{ course.mdlenrol_set.mdluserenrolments_set.count }}
```

Isso está trazendo vazio. Quando eu faço apenas o código abaixo, ele traz a quantidade de tipos de inscrição que o curso tem. Então, acredito que estou chegando perto.

```
{{ course.mdlenrol_set.count }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode filtrar os alunos dessa forma:

```
MdlUserEnrolments.objects.filter(enrolid__courseid=course.id).count()
```

Digamos que você queira colocar o valor do filtro em cada curso do contexto:

```
courses = MdlCouses.objects.all()
for course in courses:
    count = MdlUserEnrolments.objects.filter(enrolid__courseid=course.id).count()
    course.count = count
```

Agora em seu template é possivel acessar a quantidade de alunos de cada curso assim:

```
{{course.count}}
```

Comment: E como eu pegaria o nome do curso que está na outra tabela assim?

Comment: Qual campo representa o nome do curso?

Comment: Na verdade não apareceu na minha pergunta, mas fica no Model MdlCourse.

Comment: Se o campo for name então basta você fazer course.name sendo course uma instancia de MdlCouse.

Comment: É que eu preciso percorrer duas tabelas pra fazer o que eu quero. Por exemplo. Eu fiz um for percorrendo o objeto Course e trago todos os cursos. Certo ? Agora eu quero saber a quantidade de inscritos no curso. Daí eu tenho que andar até a tabela de MdlUserEnrolments. Mas essa tabela não tem o ID do curso. Ela tem o ID do Tipo de inscrição, que é o model MdlEnrol.

Comment: Por causa disso não consigo chegar onde quero.

Comment: Então, da forma como fiz você obtem a informação que você quer. Mas percebi que você quer que isto esteja na variavel course no contexto se for isso você pode adiciona-la dinamicamente. Vou fazer um exemplo na resposta.

Comment: Muito bom Hugo. Mas e dentro do template não consigo fazer isso direto?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71536/discussion-between-hugo-brilhante-and-diego-souza).

Comment: Estranho, esse relacionamento não funcionou.

Comment: Funcionou agora. Preciso eu fazer um pequeno ajuste. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Da uma pesquisada sobre o `select_related`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/

Com ele vc pode percorrer suas tabelas de formas mais otimizada como:

`user = MdlUserEnrolments.objects.select_related('enrolid')`

Ai pra acessar os campos ta tabela relacionada vc pode usar no template:

`{% for u in user %}
Estatos do MdlUserEnrolments: {{ u.status }}
Estatos do enrolid: {{ u.enrolid.status }} 
{% endfor %}`

Eu só fiz com 2 tabelas até agora, mas se não me engano vc pode fazer algo tipo: `u.enrolid.courseid.fullname` para imprimir

Um get vc poderia fazer tipo assim `user = MdlUserEnrolments.objects.select_related('enrolid').get(enrolid__status=10)`